# Access is it possible to develop DB for a client with diffrent version of outlook

Tags: email, ms-access, outlook, static-libraries

I get a error with our database when I run it on a client PC

> > Our database contains a missing or borken reference to the file "MSOUTL.OLB" version 9.5

I developped a DB using Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object library (I have Office 2013 on my development PC). I need this reference to send email with Outlook.

I wonder it is possible to compile the DB in order to run it a PC where Outlook 2007 is install ? It is an headhache to have the same environment on the development and the client PCs. Do you have any workaround or do I have to install Outlook 2013 on the client computer workstation ?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Yes, use late bindings.

Comment: The main issue is whether the Outlook 2007 library still supports all the Outlook 2013 functionality your database is using. If you manually change the References on the client's computer to point to the Outlook 2007 library, does everything work?

Comment: I tried but I don't know how to change the reference on the client's computer (they only have an ACCESS runtime). Could you explain in further détails ?

Comment: Erik von Asmuth : I tried late binding (please have a look to the code below) but #error 2046 happens. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the problem. Some reports used DoCmd.SendObject to send the PDF report by email. This call returns the error. I replace it by a late bindint send email function (with Outlook.Application) and it works well on all the computers.